# Reading multiple text file in Java

Tags: java, recursion, readfile

I have few text files. Each text file contains some path and/or the reference of some other file.

File1

```
#file#>D:/FilePath/File2.txt   
Mod1>/home/admin1/mod1
Mod2>/home/admin1/mod2
```

File2

```
Mod3>/home/admin1/mod3
Mod4>/home/admin1/mod4
```

All I want is, copy all the paths `Mod1, Mod2, Mod3, Mod4` in another text file by supplying only `File1.txt` as input to my java program.

What I have done till now?

```
public void readTextFile(String fileName){
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(fileName)));
            String line = br.readLine();

            while(line!=null){

                if(line.startsWith("#file#>")){
                    String string[] = line.split(">");
                    readTextFile(string[1]);
                }
                else if(line.contains(">")){
                    String string[] = line.split(">");                  
                    svnLinks.put(string[0], string[1]);
                }               
                line=br.readLine();
            }           
        } catch (Exception e) {         
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Currently my code reads the contents of `File2.txt` only, control does not come back to `File1.txt`.
Please ask if more inputs are required.

Comment: Please add comment after down vote.

Comment: The second file may also contain the '#file#>D:/FilePath/File3.txt' type of line. Is it right?

Answer (score 0):

Seems pretty simple. You need to write your file once your `svnLinks` `Map` is populated, assuming your present code works (haven't seen anything too weird in it).

So, once the `Map` is populated, you could use something along the lines of:

```
File newFile = new File("myPath/myNewFile.txt");
// TODO check file can be written
// TODO check file exists or create
FileOutputStream fos = null;
OutputStreamWriter osw = null;
BufferedWriter bw = null;
try {
    fos = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
    osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos);
    bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
    for (String key: svnLinks.keySet()) {
        bw.write(key.concat(" my separator ").concat(svnLinks.get(key)).concat("myNewLine"));
    }
}
catch (Throwable t) {
    // TODO handle more gracefully
    t.printStackTrace();
    if (bw != null) {
        try {
            bw.close();
        }
        catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Comment: Actually code is not working as expected. It only reads the contents of File2.txt i.e. output file contains Mod3>/home/admin1/mod3
Mod4>/home/admin1/mod4

Comment: @SachinMhetre No, it creates a new file with the same name for second file. So you see only the contents of the last file read.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are jumping to another file without closing the current reader and when you come back you lose the cursor. Read one file first and then write all its contents that match to another file. Close the current reader (Don't close the writer) and then open the next file to read and so on.

Comment: The sequence of the path is important. As File1.txt contains reference of File2.txt at the begining only, hence contents in File2.txt should be read first.

Comment: @SachinMhetre Then create a list first. Open file1.txt and then you see it refers to file2.txt. Add file2.txt in the list. Close file1.txt and then open file2.txt, if it refers to file3.txt, put file3.txt in the list and so on. When you have no more files to read, go through the list you created and then read in order. Did I get it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an non-recursive implementation of your method :

```
public static void readTextFile(String fileName) throws IOException {

    LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
    list.add(fileName);
    while (!list.isEmpty()) {
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(list.pop())));
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if (line.startsWith("#file#>")) {
                    String string[] = line.split(">");
                    list.add(string[1]);
                } else if (line.contains(">")) {
                    String string[] = line.split(">");
                    svnLinks.put(string[0], string[1]);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            br.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Just used a *LinkedList* to maintain the order. I suggest you to add some counter if you to limit the reading of files to a certain number(depth). eg:

```
while (!list.isEmpty() && readCount < 10 )
```

This will eliminate the chance of running the code to infinity(in case of circular reference).